# Distinct Time from Table SQL

Tags: t-sql

I have table Proccesses that consist of Date Time Field.

Proccesses ( Id as int , RunDate as DateTime)
I need to run Distinct by RunDate as Time Without seconds

```
For Example

ID        RunDate 
1         2011-12-13 12:36:26.483
2         2011-12-12 12:37:22.421
3         2011-12-11 12:36:44.421
```

I need to receive in output

```
Output
12:01
12:03
```

In order to retrieve it I using following SQL and it's working

```
SELECT DISTINCT DATENAME(hour, RunDateTime) + ':' + 
DATENAME(mi, RunDateTime) AS  d
from Proccesses
```

The problem that if minutes is less than 10 for example 8
I receiving single digit "8" , and I want to receive two digit   08

For example I receive **12:8** , and I need to receive **12:08**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
RIGHT ('00' + CAST(DATENAME(hour, RunDateTime) AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) + ':' +
RIGHT ('00' + CAST(DATENAME(mi, RunDateTime) AS VARCHAR(2)), 2)
from Proccesses
```

Alternatively you can use [`CONVERT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) as suggested by [@JoeStefanelli](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8495969/847363) and handle the string result accordingly.

Comment: Great idea editing your answer to suggest CONVERT. Wish I had thought of it. Oh wait, [I did](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8495969/341251). ;-)

Comment: yes - you did... I just was googling and then pasted it into my answer... although my paste was NOT as thorough as yours since you provided a working sample with CONVERT and I did not. and now I added another EDIT :-)

Answer (score 0):

[CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) style 108 will return hh:mm:ss. Using CHAR(5) for the data type will return just the hh:mm portion.

```
SELECT DISTINCT CONVERT(CHAR(5), RunDateTime, 108) AS d
    FROM Processes
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,RunDateTime),7)
```

You could strip of the AM/PM if you want to.